Controling number of elements on type level
Lets assume we want to have type representing two elements array in typescript.
Its simpe
type twoElementsArray = number[] & { length : 2}; 

Now lets try same trick with Set
type twoElementsSet = Set & {size : 2} 

const setOfTwo: twoElementsSet = new Set([1,2])

Now we have an error Type 'number' is not assignable to type '2'
Which looks a bit awkward. What is also worth noting while
trick with array works here
const arrayOfTwo : twoElementsArray = [1,2] 

It doesn't here
const anotherArrayOfTwo: twoElementsArray = new Array(1,2); 

Do you have idea how one can enforce consistent behaviour so no matter how Array is constructed it can control number of elements on type level as well as Array/Set/Map whatever data structure symmetry ?

• It looks like you're asking multiple questions; one is about "consistent" Array behavior, the other is about arbitrary sized collections; please [edit] this to ask a single primary question, or it risks being closed with "Needs more focus: This question currently includes multiple questions in one. It should focus on one problem only."

(see prev comment) • The only reason number[] & { length : 2}; works is because tuple types exist, so number[] & {length: 2} is probably strictly less usable than [number, number]. If this question ends up being about arrays, then I'd say you want to use tuples. If there's a reason you're avoiding tuples, please [edit] to say why.

@jcalz this is an answer i was looking for.
